# Can Tensorflow Lite models be used for inference on Windows 10?

Tags: tensorflow-lite

I converted an existing SavedModel to TFLite:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("/path/to/original_model")
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with open("/path/to/optimized_model.tflite", 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

And tried to load it:

```
interp = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path="/path/to/optimized_model.tflite")
my_signature = interp.get_signature_runner()
```

After which I got this error:

```
ValueError: SignatureDef method_name is None and model has 0 Signatures. None is only allowed when the model has 1 SignatureDef
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Running Windows 10 with TF2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the TensorFlow version 2.5, only the models, converted from the `from_saved_model` API, will have a signature.

Comment: Wow very strange but it worked... Didn't shorten inference time comparing to the original Keras model though.